# How can i add pin google maps one more time?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have problem about google maps.I want to add pin when i touch the maps .I used this post when i do project.  [this is maps link](http://codemagician.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/android-google-mapview-tutorial-done-right/)

My problem is i can add pin just one time.But i want to add a lot of time.I dont understand what is problem.Can anybody help me?

my code is here:

```
package com.example;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.maps.*;

import java.util.List;

public class HelloGoogleMaps2 extends MapActivity
{
    MapView mapView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapView.isClickable();

      // GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(50443769,-71158458);
      // GeoPoint point=new GeoPoint(0,0);
       // AddMyPin(point);

        mapView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                 return onTouch2(view,motionEvent);

            }
        });

    }


    public boolean onTouch2(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == 0) {
            GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                    (int) motionEvent.getX(),
                    (int) motionEvent.getY());

           GeoPoint gp= new GeoPoint((int)motionEvent.getX(),(int)motionEvent.getY());

            AddMyPin(p);

        }

       return  false;

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void AddMyPin(GeoPoint point)
    {
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble);
        HelloItemizedOverlays itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlays(drawable,this);

        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,null,null);


        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

        mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);


    }

}
```

Comment: @Marvin i added pin just 1 time.If I want to add one more time it doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your method to this:

```
public void AddMyPin(GeoPoint point)
{    
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble);
        HelloItemizedOverlays itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlays(drawable,this);

        OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,null,null);


        itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);

        mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay);

        //this will cause the map to redraw with the new overlay 
        mapView.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work.Still i can add just one pin.Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably from your HelloItemizedOverlays class.
I think that you are not populating it again once you create.That's why you just get one pin and then nothing else after first time.

Since populate is a final method that you cant call outside the itemizedoverlay class.
You can make a public method in your HelloItemizedOverlays class which can call populate on your request.

Something like this in your HelloItemizedOverlays class.

```
public void populateList() {
    populate();
}
```

And in your AddMyPin method.

```
 public void AddMyPin(GeoPoint point)
{
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble);
    HelloItemizedOverlays itemizedoverlay = new HelloItemizedOverlays(drawable,this);

    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,null,null);


    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    itemizedoverlay.populateList();

    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
    mapView.invalidate();


}
```